# Sublime Text 3: NodeJS build system terminates process (Windows)

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3

So I have installed the `Nodejs` package and the `.sublime-build` file looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.js",
    "shell": false,
    "encoding": "cp1252",
    "windows":
    {
        "shell_cmd": "taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node $file"
    },
    ...
}
```

And I have a basic JS file...

```
let check = true;
let funcToCheck = (check) => {
    console.log(check);
}
funcToCheck();
```

The issue is whenever I try to build the JS file, I get:

> SUCCESS: The process "node.exe" with PID 1308 has been terminated.

So it is terminating the process that has been created but is not actually logging anything to the console. I have looked at many examples on how the `.sublime-build` should look but cannot see where it is wrong

Comment: sublime is probably just checking the exit code, try process.exit(1) when your check fails, and process.exit(0) for success

Comment: @Catalyst attempted this and unfortunately is not the solution. Made my JS file even simpler by rewriting to...`console.log("Hello world");` but same error even with checking the exit code